# How to write a function wrapper for cout that allows for expressive syntax?

Tags: c++, wrapper, cout

I'd like to wrap `std::cout` for formatting, like so:

```
mycout([what type?] x, [optional args]) {
    ... // do some formatting on x first
    std::cout << x;
}
```

and still be able to use expressive syntax like

```
mycout("test" << i << endl << somevar, indent)
```

instead of being forced to be more verbose like

```
mycout(std::stringstream("test") << i ...)
```

How can I implement this? What type to make `x`?

*Edit: added consideration for optional arguments*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this:

```
struct MyCout {};

extern MyCout myCout;

template <typename T>
MyCout& operator<< (MyCout &s, const T &x) {
  //format x as you please
  std::cout << x;
  return s;
}
```

And put `MyCout myCout;` into any one .cpp file.

You can then use `myCout` like this:

```
myCout << "test" << x << std::endl;
```

And it will call the template `operator<<` which can do the formatting.

Of course, you can also provide overloads of the operator for special formatting of specific types if you want to.

**EDIT**

Apparently (thanks to @soon), for standard manipulators to work, a few more overloads are necessary:

```
MyCout& operator<< (MyCout &s, std::ostream& (*f)(std::ostream &)) {
  f(std::cout);
  return s;
}

MyCout& operator<< (MyCout &s, std::ostream& (*f)(std::ios &)) {
  f(std::cout);
  return s;
}

MyCout& operator<< (MyCout &s, std::ostream& (*f)(std::ios_base &)) {
  f(std::cout);
  return s;
}
```

---

**EDIT 2**

I may have misunderstoor your original requirements slightly. How about this (plus the same manipulator overloads as above):

```
struct MyCout
{
  std::stringstream s;

  template <typename T>
  MyCout& operator << (const T &x) {
    s << x;
    return *this;
  }

  ~MyCout() {
    somehow_format(s);
    std::cout << s.str();
  }
};

int main() {
  double y = 1.5;
  MyCout() << "test" << y;
}
```

Comment: "`myCout << ... << std::endl;`" will not works(in your case), since `operator<<` isn't overloaded for `endl` function.

Comment: Thanks - how could optional arguments additionally be implemented? Overloading comma operator? e.g. `myCout << "array" << myarr, indent, seperator`

Comment: @MiloChen That should work, with custom types and singleton instances for `indent` and `separator`.

Comment: In your edits, should you not be returning `s` rather than `myCout`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't this will work if you want to format the entire line of input at once (e.g. `"test" << ... << x`) right? For example, part of the purpose of my formatter is to always put an `endl` at the end of each line. Would this not add an `endl` after each of `"test"`, ..., `x`?

Comment: I must have misunderstood your original requirements; added another approach to answer. It's a nice problem :-)

Comment: Thanks. What is the significance of `struct MyCout`? Why not just have classes?

Comment: @MiloChen `struct` and `class` are almost the same in C++. `struct` uses `public` access by default and `class` uses `private`, but they're otherwise identical.

Comment: Oh OK, didnt realise that compiler would be so pedantic. I think also `~MyCout` should print `s.str()`

Comment: @MiloChen Added a `str()` call.

Comment: Changed this to accepted answer, as this provides such a complete and elegant solution to my problem. Making this into a class with a constructor, you can start passing optional parameters like `myCout(indent, ...) << "hello" << x` which is exactly what I'm after.

Comment: @MiloChen Happy to have helped :-)

Answer (score 5):

This comes easy with variadic template arguments:

```
template <class T>
void print(T t)
{
    std::cout << t;
}

template <class T, class... Args>
void print(T t, Args... args)
{
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
    print(args...);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    print(3, 's', true, false);
}
```

Output:

> `3`
>   `s`
>   `true`
>   `false`

[***Live Demo***](http://ideone.com/FP1W3b#view_edit_box)

Comment: What about consideration for optional arguments e.g. indenting, various delimiters, units?

Comment: And also is it possible to pass the varadic args by reference?

Comment: @MiloChen A) This function takes *any* type, so I'm sure you'll be able to pass those values in. B) Yes, you can pass varadic arguments by reference by using the `Args&...` syntax. rvalue-reference: `Args&&...`

Answer (score 1):

A variation from the answers:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyCout 
{
public:
  MyCout& operator()(bool indent) { 
    if ( indent ) cout << '\t'; 
    return *this;
  }

  template<class T>
  MyCout& operator<<(T t) {
    cout << t;
    return *this;
  }

  MyCout& operator<<(ostream& (*f)(ostream& o)) {
    cout << f;
    return *this;
  };
};

int main()
{
  MyCout mycout;
  int x = 10;
  mycout(true)<< "test" << 2 << x << endl ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this kind of class:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class CustomOut
{
public:

    template<class T>
    CustomOut& operator<<(const T& obj)
    {
        cout << " my-cout " << obj;
        return *this;
    }

};

int main()
{
    CustomOut mycout;
    mycout << "test" << 4 << "\n" << 3.4;
}
```

You'd need more code to use std::endl and other functors, so i've used here simple \n instead.