# How to copy std::cout to std::ofstream

Tags: c++

I know how to use the rdbuf method to redirect the std::cout stream to std::ofstream but I wanted to "copy" the contents of std::cout to std::ofstream so that I only have to call std::cout and the message goes both to std::cout and std::ofstream?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18331432/179910. You'll have to write to the object you create instead of `cout`, but otherwise exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: If you want to capture the output of a program in a file and still have it available as "normal" output, use the `tee` program. Yep, doesn't answer your question but hopefully gives you what you want instead. ;)