# What is `std::ostream& (*f)(std::ostream &)` when overloading `<<` and why I would need it?

Tags: c++, stream, operator-overloading

I'm working in a *wrapper* for `boost.log` and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444119/how-to-write-a-function-wrapper-for-cout-that-allows-for-expressive-syntax) question that seems to be what I want, but instead of `std::cout` would be something related to the `boost` stream that I don't really know yet. For that, I stuck wondering why it is needed and what it's actually doing. For example:

```
MyCout& operator<< (MyCout &s, std::ostream& (*f)(std::ios &)) {
    f(std::cout);
    return s;
}
```

In this case I understand (or maybe not?) that I'm overloading the operator `<<` for `MyCout` using the `std::ostream& (*f)(std::ios &)`, but why is that? What the `f(std::cout)` actually does and why I would need to overload the operator with this function? It seems that `s` is not been used at all, just passing through the operator and returning the same as before.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::ostream& (*f)(std::ios &)` is a function pointer named `f` and it points to function that takes a `std::ios &` as its only parameter and returns a `std::ostream&`.  This is needed for some of the [stream manipulators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) like [`std::endl`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl), which is a function, not an object like `std::cout` is.

With this overload you can stream a function into your stream and have that function do some sort of manipulation of the stream

---

Do not that this function signature isn't what you really want.  The input parameter type and return type should be the same.  The standard overloads for `operator <<` that take manipulator functions are

```
basic_ostream& operator<<(
    std::ios_base& (*func)(std::ios_base&) );

basic_ostream& operator<<(
    std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>& (*func)(std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>&) );

basic_ostream& operator<<(
    std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& (*func)(std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&) );

basic_istream& operator>>( 
    std::ios_base& (*func)(std::ios_base&) );

basic_istream& operator>>( 
    std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>& (*func)(std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>&) );

basic_istream& operator>>( 
    basic_istream& (*func)(basic_istream&) );
```

Comment: I'd question the strange use of taking `std::ios` as an argument and returning an `std::ostream`. Usually the return type and parameter have to match for it to work intuitively, there's little sense to make them differ.

Comment: Thanks! The knowledge that std::cout is a function was just vanished from my mind.

Comment: @Eric `std::cout` is an object (an instance of the class `std::ostream`). The `std::ostream` class overload the `<<` operator so that `std::endl` (a function) can appear on the righthand side of the operator (i.e `std::cout << "hello" << std::endl`).

Comment: @0x499602D2 Oh, sure! I meant endl, just too much cout on my head at the time. I need a break lol